# Are library recommenations on or off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is the exchange limited to executable software or are libraries and APIs allowed?

Example questions:

> What Android library would you recommend for async image loading?
>
> Is there a public League of Legends API that I can use?

Comment: For APIs, see [Are web API recommendations on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/716/60)